# Difference between .map and .times when calling a method

Tags: ruby

I want to call a method multiple times. Both ways below worked but I don´t understand the difference. Can someone clarify it?

```
class Dog
    def bark
        puts 'Wow!'
    end
end

dog = Dog.new
3.times do dog.bark end
3.times.map { dog.bark }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[map](http://ruby-doc.org//core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.

[times](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-times) iterates the given block provided number of times and returns the number of iterations it made. (3 in your case)

In the following case the return value is `3`:

```
val = 3.times do dog.bark end
Wow!
Wow!
Wow!
# => 3
val
# => 3
```

However when `map` is used, you would get an array of `nil`. (because you are not returning anything in your method)

```
val = 3.times.map { dog.bark }
Wow!
Wow!
Wow!
# => [nil, nil, nil] 
val
# => [nil, nil, nil]
```

Since your method is intended only to print the output, it does not matter to you what is returned and hence you cannot distinguish between the two.

A better way of understanding this is by returning some value from your method. Here:

```
class Dog
    def bark
        1
    end
end

dog = Dog.new
```

Now you can easily notice the differences as discussed above:

```
3.times do dog.bark end
# => 3
3.times.map { dog.bark }
# => [1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, shivam. I now understand. That means that if I were to get the first 4 numbers of the fibonacci sequence I would call the method using the `4.times.map { fibonacci }` and I would get the array [1, 2, 3, 5].

Comment: It depends on the logic sitting inside `fibonacci`. However I think above mentioned way shows bad design. Your method `fibonacci` should take an input parameter (say n) and return the series of that length.

Comment: Shivam, yes, that makes sense. Thanks, learned a lot from you!

Comment: sure. glad to be of help :)

Comment: Another point: if you instead used the block `{ |i| dog.bark(i) }` and modified the `bark` method to take a parameter, you would see that it was called with `1` then `2` then `3` as `3.times` passes up a new number each time.

Comment: To be precise, `map` returns an array of nils because `puts` returns nil.